# Getting crash in Android on onResume() in my activity - Why?

Tags: java, android, crash, onresume

The error is:

**Unable to resume activity: java.lang.NullPointerException**

Here is the stack trace:

```
0 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.sortitapps.movies/com.sortitapps.movies.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
1 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2944)
2 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2973)
3 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
4 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
5 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
6 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
7 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
8 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
9 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
12 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
13 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
14 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
15 at com.sortitapps.movies.SettingsActivity.onResume(SettingsActivity.java:149)
16 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1259)
17 at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5200)
18 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
```

And here is the code. **Line 149 is adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**:

```
@Override
public void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);

    int numberDesktop = settings.getInt("desktop", 0);
    Log.i("Desktop purchased:", String.valueOf(numberDesktop));

    int numberScans = settings.getInt("scanning", 0);
    Log.i("Number of scans:", String.valueOf(numberScans));

    if (settingsitems.contains("Unlock Desktop Apps") &&
            numberDesktop == 2)
    {
        settingsitems.remove("Unlock Desktop Apps");
    }

    String freeapp = getResources().getString(R.string.free_app);

    if (settingsitems.contains("Unlock Premium Features") &&
            freeapp.equals("Yes") && 
            numberScans > 10)
    {
        settingsitems.remove("Unlock Premium Features");
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Do I need to initialize the adapter again when coming resuming?

Comment: **adapter** is null. check it..

Comment: Show code where you declare your adapter and where you initialise it.

Comment: It's initialized in another part of the code before going in the background. Is it normal that adapters go null and need to be reinitialized in onResume?

Comment: Are you shure that settingsitems is initialized?

Comment: @EthanAllen : "It's initialized in another part of the code" - OK, show that code and No, an adapter won't be nullified under normal circumstances.

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, I think I found a situation where the adapter could be null... thank you for the tips.

Comment: OK I see that I had an `if` in `onCreate` that could bypass the initialization of the adapter in certain situations. It's now fixed. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Most certainly adapter is null.

Your code doesn't show how the adapter got initialized, so it could be that it wasn't initialized with a value, or it was set to null after that.

Comment: This isn't an answer as you haven't seen the OP's code or provided a concrete solution. The adapter is definitely null but this should have been a comment.

Comment: The only way a NPE on 149 to be thrown is adapter null. The only alternative would have been an NPE thrown in notifyDataSetChanged, but then the line number would be different.

Comment: That wasn't my point. My point is you haven't actually provided an answer. All you've done is state the obvious. We've all worked out that the adapter is null but without seeing further code it is impossible to provide a solution to the problem. Simply say the adapter is null is not an answer - it should be a comment.

Comment: It was the obvious for you and me. We both could see it immediately.